# How to bind to hasMany length on Ember Data model without triggering a network request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I'd like to have a computed property called `hasChildren` on my ember data model that looks like this.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({

  children: hasMany(),

  hasChildren: Ember.computed('children.[]', function() {
    return this.hasMany('children').ids().length > 0;
  })

});
```

Unfortunately, the above still triggers a trip to the server.

One of the workarounds I can think of is to have a `volatile` computed property.

However, I would like to know if there's a way to bind to `hasMany.length` and not trigger a network request. Or maybe there's a way to bind to the `hasMany.ids` or `hasMany.value` somehow.

Comment: Not 100% sure about this but have you tried `Ember.get(this, 'children').ids().length`

Comment: Depending on the data returned for this model, the client may not know how many children the model has.  It could just a url to query in order to resolve the relationship.  In that case your options are: loadthe children ahead of this query so the Store has a copy and can determine length (e.g. side-load), or accept the server request.  Fairly sure, if I understand the question correctly, that volatile will not help you here.

Comment: Isn't the default behaviour to side load relationships? So it would need the extra call to get the number of children? How does making the relationship synchonous work? `children: hasMany('children', {async: false})`. Of course, this will only work if the data is returned with the original query